# Inspect Devices Chrome auto reopen/reload

Tags: android, cordova, google-chrome, device, phonegap

I am currently usings chromes fantastic `Inspect Devices` to debug my phonegap app.

However every single time I build the app and deploy to my phone I will get the following message:

> Detached from the target etc

[image]

Is it possible to get Chrome to auto reload so I don't have to keep opening

`Settings -> More Tools -> Inspect Devices`

Comment: I made a bookmark directly to the inspect devices page, it doesn't solve the problem but it helps

Comment: Ye, I had to as well as I found it so hard to find it again lol

Comment: I am not believe, that this question still does not have correct answer. This functional is must have.

Answer (score -1):

As far I know, at this moment it is possible to do it only by reload page. It will reload the code (HTML, js, CSS), but the history of WebView will not be cleared. By that I mean that if your app start on "http://start", and you are currently on url "http://a/b" and do reload, you will be now on "http://start", but click on back will not terminate app, you will be redirected on "http://a/b". If that is not problem, then relaod is your solution. Regards.

Comment: Ohhhh I've never hit reload on the page.

Comment: Once the app is disconnected after re-installing/deploying it through phonegap or cordova, refreshing said debugging view does not bring it back; you have to close it and reconnect to the new chrome browser session.